# jQuery/html dropdown box values stay the same after ajax load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Currently, I have a hierarchy style (3 levels) drop down box system of navigating through some webpages. The second level has 3 different options, Digital Inputs, Digital Outputs and Analog Inputs. The third level, has two options for all three of those options stated above, Show Displayed Only, Show All. My problem right now is that every time I press "Show Displayed Only" in any of those 3 options, it displays the same webpage every time, how would I go about making it so the correct versions of "Show Displayed Only" are displayed?

Second question is, whenever a new page is loaded, the hierarchy of dropdowns are defaulted back to the first option in each box, how would I make it so the hierarchy of boxes stay at the value I put them at upon the page change?

This is the code I'm currently using to read the drop down boxes and display the correct page:

```
$("#bottom").on("change", function(event){


                var selection = $( "#bottom option:selected" ).text();

                 console.log(selection);

                 switch (selection) {
                     case "Basic Info":
                        menuPageLoad("#/ajax/settings/device_settings/device_details/basic_info.html");
                        break;
                    case "Site Details":
                        menuPageLoad("#/ajax/settings/device_settings/device_details/site_details.html");
                        break;
                    case "Show Displayed Only":
                         menuPageLoad("#/ajax/settings/device_settings/digital_inputs/show_displayed_only.1.html");
                         break; 
                    case "Show All":
                         menuPageLoad("#/ajax/settings/device_settings/digital_inputs/show_all.html");
                         break; 

                 }

            });
```

My hierarchy:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Settings:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select id="top" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Select">Select</option>
                        <option value="Settings">Device Settings</option>
                        <option value="Groups">Device Groups</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <br /><br />


                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Section:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select id="middle" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Select">Select</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Details">Device Details</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Notification">Notification List</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Digital">Digital Inputs</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Analog">Analog Inputs</option>
                        <option value="Settings--DigiO">Digital Outputs</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Geofencing">Geofencing</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Application">Application Specific</option>
                        <option value="Groups--GroupDet">Group Details</option>
                        <option value="Groups--GroupDev">Group Devices</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>


                    <br /><br />


                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Device Details:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select id="bottom" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Settings--Select">Select</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Details--BasicInfo">Basic Info</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Details--SiteDetails">Site Details</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Details--DistrInfo">Distributor Information</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Details--CustInfo">Customer Information</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Notification--Add">Add or Edit</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Notification--Import">Import Notification List</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Digital--Displayed">Show Displayed Only</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Digital--All">Show All</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Analog--Displayed">Show Displayed Only</option>
                        <option value="Settings--Analog--All">Show All</option>
                        <option value="Settings--DigiO--Displayed">Show Displayed Only</option>
                        <option value="Settings--DigiO--All">Show All</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

MenuPageLoad():

```
var default_content2 = '<div class="p-t-40 p-b-40 text-center f-s-20 content"><i class="fa fa-warning fa-lg text-muted m-r-5"></i> <span class="f-w-600 text-inverse">Error 404! Page not found.</span></div>';

            var menuPageLoad = function(hash) {
                //Pace.restart();
                var targetUrl = hash.replace('#','');
                $('.jvectormap-label, .jvector-label, .AutoFill_border ,#gritter-notice-wrapper, .ui-autocomplete, .colorpicker, .FixedHeader_Header, .FixedHeader_Cloned .lightboxOverlay, .lightbox').remove();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: targetUrl, //with the page number as a parameter
                    dataType: 'html',   //expect html to be returned
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#ajax-content').html(data);
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $("body").offset().top
                        }, 250);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#ajax-content').html(default_content2);
                    }
                });
            };
```

Comment: where is `menuPageLoad()`?

Comment: Seems like your "show displayed only" test is matching and triggering the appropriate URL in the switch case https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmLJaZ

Comment: Edited with menuPageLoad()